# Cached HTML Resource not reloaded by Browser

Tags: html, caching

I have a webserver serving an HTML document, let's say http://example.com/ 
returns an index.html document, which has the content

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://some-other-domain.com/">
```

This document is cached (I dont why) in my browser:

In Firefox, I list the cache via
about:cache?storage=disk
and see the entry

```
http://example.com/ Expires: 1.10.2016
```

Now I redesigned my web-page and want the user to see the new content, but all users, who have visited my site before, have the cache entry and are still redirected to http://some-other-domain.com/.

Is there any chance to solve the problem without clearing the browser cache of each user?

Regards,
Björn

Comment: There will not be a 100% effective way to _force_ a browser to request a new version. You can suggest it via `cache-control` headers from the webserver, but some browsers might not even re-check that until the expiry date.

Answer (score 0):

This link tells you everything, depending on whether you're on a Mac or PC and which browser you're in! 
https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/#.Vp-52BqAOko

I would do command + shift + R